# Same motivation letter for the same project but in two different places?

Tags: application, postdocs, application-cover-letter, projects

Let us assume that I have applied for a post doc position in place X on a project Y in collaboration with university Z, and they asked for a personal statement.

A week later, another post doc position appeared in place Z on the same project Y and in collaboration with university X.

Since I am very interested in the project, I'd like to maximize my opportunity to obtain the position on the project and I'd like to apply to this second position as well.

Do you think I should say this to the prof. related to my first application (since it might be that they are in contact and exchanging information)?

And a second question regards the personal statement: in the second post-doc position, they ask o a letter of motivation. How bad is if I just copy and paste the previous letter (just changing the properly the name of the institution inside)? I mean, I wrote the letter for the **same** project, my motivation are there, but I was wondered that they might exchange information and this might look bad.

Since these are my first post-doc application I don't really know how they used to manage these things..

Comment: Please only ask one question per post

Comment: @Sursula-they- should I ask the two questions with the same story in two different post?

Answer (score 2):

You can assume that they will talk to each other, since they are hiring for the same project.

When applying to the second position, you should mention that you have already applied for the first position. Thus, duplication of the motivation part is understood and anything else would in fact raise eyebrows.

It could be that there is in fact only one position, and hiring can be done either through X or through Z, but both will have to comply with their own internal procedures, which makes it appear as if there are two positions.